# Using Maven SmartSprites With Sass

Tags: css, maven, sass

I'm using [SmartSprites](http://csssprites.org/) with SCSS.

SmartSprites requires that [Sprite Reference Directives](http://csssprites.org/#usage) must look like so:

```
background-image:url('image.png'); /** sprite-ref: mysprite; */
```

In other words, I need comments at the end of my background-image declarations in my compiled CSS file, but [none of the four output_styles of Sass](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style) allow this to happen. After compiling:

**:nested** or **:expanded**

```
background-image:url('image.png');
/** sprite-ref: mysprite; */
```

**:compact**

```
.selector { background-image:url('image.png'); /** sprite-ref: mysprite; */ }
```

**:compressed**

```
.selector{background-image:url('image.png');}
```

Under any of these settings, running Maven to generate the sprite with SmartSprites reports a build failure.

***The solution must...***

- adhere to SmartSprite's formatting requirements (i.e. have comments at the end of the same line)
- work automatically (no manual action required for formatting)
- not be specific to any single text-editor
- not abandon SCSS (because cavemen do otherwise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [maven-replacer-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/) to format the stylesheet during the Maven build process.

In pom.xml, insert the following inside maven-replacer-plugin's `<executions>`:

```
<execution>
    <id>smartsprite-formatting</id>
    <phase>process-sources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>replace</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <basedir>src/main/my-project</basedir>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.css</include>
        </includes>
        <replacements>
            <replacement>
                <token>;\s*?\n.*/\*\*</token>
                <value>; /\*\*</value>
            </replacement>
        </replacements>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Ensure that the filepath in `<basedir>` is correct and the `<phase>` is set to a phase in the [Maven Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) that occurs before SmartSprites is run. `process-sources` is pretty ideal, so it may not have to be changed.